# Manipulating a list inside a dictionary (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm kinda new to python but trying to catch up and I have a question about manipulating a list inside a dictionary.
Find below the dictionary structure:

```
{0: ['LU0', 1, 6597604, 7062193, 464590, 0, 0]}
{1: ['LU0', 2, 7392407, 7615509, 223103, 0, 1]}
{2: ['LU0', 3, 1478083, 1978082, 500000, 0, 4]}
{3: ['LU0', 4, 7633406, 7795137, 161732, 0, 5]}
{4: ['LU1', 1, 0, 1023, 1024, 1, 0]}
{5: ['LU1', 2, 0, 1023, 1024, 1, 0]}
{6: ['LU2', 1, 0, 511, 512, 0, 0]}
```

I'd like to send the [2] and [3] elements inside the list for a specific
function based on the [0] elements, meaning, have a temporary lists which will look like this:

for 'LU0':

```
[6597604, 7062193, 7392407, 7615509, 1478083, 1978082, 7633406, 7795137]
```

for 'LU1':

```
[0, 1023, 0, 1023]
```

for 'LU2':

```
[0, 511]
```

each one of the above will be sent to `allocPer(sourceList)`
as the sourceList and get back the returned value which will be saved to other
list inside a dictionary as the [5]th element with the following structure (the key is the LUx value):

```
{0: [7808000, 8, 8, 0, 24, 0]}
{1: [1024, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
{2: [512, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Thanks in advance ;)
LH

Comment: What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: How do I do that? how do I write an efficient, generic code that will produce this temporary list, send it to the "allocPer" function one at a time and save the result to the below structure.

Comment: Have you tried to write anything yourself or you just want someone to write code for you? Your questions should be more specific. If you don't know how to work with dictionaries and lists in python, then read tutorials and work through examples.

Comment: Well, I've tried looking in this forum and in few tutorials and couldn't find the answer since it's too specific. taking values which are inside a list which is inside a dictionary by a condition is not that common. I can do with answer only on this part (1st part until sending the output list to a function).

Comment: Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

One way to access a list inside a dictionary is the same way you access nested dictionaries, but using the list's index at the appropriate point.
  Example: dictname[0][2] and dictname[0][3], but you need to have the nested dictionaries structured properly for access.